# Linotp radius module chap

Tags: linux, authentication, freeradius, radius, totp

I installed linotp with radius module. I can't login using chap and mschap. Only pap works.

**cat /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/linotp**

```
server linotp {
  listen {
    ipaddr = *
    port = 1812
    type = auth
  }

  listen {
    ipaddr = *
    port = 1813
    type = acct
  }

  authorize {
    files
    perl
    if (ok || updated) {
        update control {
            Auth-Type := Perl
        }
    }
    preprocess
    chap
    mschap
    pap
    suffix
    unix
    update {
      &control:Auth-Type := Perl
    }
  }

  authenticate {
    Auth-Type Perl {
      perl
    }
  }

  accounting {
    unix
  }

}
```

Different docker containers.